# Laravel9 で config('app.env') が常に local を返してくる

Tags: laravel

Laravel9 で local時のみ実行する判断用に config('app.env') を使おうとしています。
しかしながら、上手くいきません。
**.env をどのように設定しても、常に local を返してきます。**

| .env APP_ENV= | dd(config('app.env')) |
| --- | --- |
| local | local |
| test | local |
| production | local |

`.env.test` などの他のファイルは存在していません
`.env.example` は `APP_ENV=local_example` にしてあります

#### 試したこと

- キャッシュのクリア `sail artisan config:clear`
  キャッシュファイルが存在しないことを確認 `bootstrap/cache/config.php`
- `config/app.php` のAPP_ENV をAPP_NAMEに変更してテスト
  `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),`
  `'env' => env('APP_NAME', 'production'),` 結果 `laravel9local` と .env の内容表示
- `sail artisan env` で `.env APP_ENV` に設定した `test` になることを確認
- .env の中に `APP_ENV` の指定はひとつだけ
- .env から `APP_ENV` を削除しました。結果 `local` を出力
- sail の停止と開始をすると「開始」したときの APP_ENV を保持している。APP_NAME などは保持せず変更した直後に値が変わる

#### 疑問点

なぜ、他の .env の値は正常に取り出すことができるのに
APP_ENV だけが常に local を返してくるのかがわかりません

原因、解決方法、問題の可能性について教えていただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: sailを使用されているようですが、コンテナの再起動はどのように行ってますか？コマンド等を追記ください。（upしなおしてますか？）

Comment: はい。実行しています。実行したタイミングで、設定されていた APP_ENV が返ってきます。再起動後に変更した値を取得することができません

Comment: すみません。質問読み間違えました。コマンドはsail down とsail up -d で実行しています

Answer (score 0):

```
App::environment()
```

で環境名を得られないでしょうか

Comment: App::environment()　試してみたところ、
.env APP_ENV=test の状態で local が返ってきました
一度、sailを停止して再起動。
.env APP_ENV=local　にすると test が返ってきました。
試したこと、にある状態と同じでsailが起動したときの値を保持しているようです

Comment: キャッシュされてるならサーバー再起動で反映されるかもしれないですね